# Regular Expressiong - Check Email Address Valid or Value is N/A

Tags: regex, validation

I wonder if anyone could make a suggestion how i achieve the following?

I have a regex which suffices in the validation of email addresses which is as follows:

```
^(\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b)*$
```

Its a loose validator but as i said, it suffices for what we need. What I need to do if possible is validate on the following criteria:

1) validate email addresses based on the above format
2) if not an email address as above, check if value is N/A or n/a

Appreciate anyones help,

Thanks

Jon

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: validating an email address was not the problem outlined here, the problem was that I had not even considered the or operator in allowing for varying patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little modifications to your original expression you can acheive what you wanted...
You can use Or operator to match multiple patterns. (PatternA)|(PatternB)|(PatternC) will match for all three patterns A, B & C. So, below should work.

`((\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\b))|(N/A)|(n/a)`

Or the below should also work

`([\w-\._\+%]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6})|(N/A)|(n/a)`

Source: http://RegExr.com?3563b

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
^(\b[Nn]\/[Aa]|(?:[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})\b)$
```